# Wordpress loop only displays 5 articles max?

Tags: loop

Right, I been playing around with my code for a bot now, and still can't come up with a solution to my problem. I have custom post types with custom fields and a custom taxonomy ("lieux") with different terms. I have created a hierarchical page to display the articles by taxonomy term : taxonomy-lieux.php This is the code :

```
<div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_3_4">
 <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">
     <h1><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
      $i++;?>
         <div class="portfolio<?php if ( ($i%3) == 0 ) { echo ' last'; } elseif ( ($i%2) == 0 ) { echo ' two-last'; } elseif ( ($i%4) == 0 ) { echo ' very-large'; } ?>" data-thematique="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('thematique')); ?>" data-activite="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('activite')); ?>" data-niveau="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('niveau')); ?>">
                                <div class="project-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                                <div class="project-info">
                                <span class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">NIVEAU :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('niveau'); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">THÉMATIQUE :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('thematique'); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">ACTIVITÉ :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('activite'); ?></span></span>
                                      <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">Lieu : </span><span class="white"><?php echo the_field('lieu1'); ?></span></span></div><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="button portfolio-button">EN SAVOIR PLUS</a>
                            </div>

      <?php
      endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?></div> 

      </div></div>
```

Problem is : my page only displays 5 custom post types max ! I think something's wrong with my loop, does anybody know what ? 
Oh by the way : I have already tried changing the number of posts to display in the backend, and I've also tried adding `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=-1' );` in my loop, it didn't work, it only displayed the "Hello world" article...
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: check your setting in wp-admin for "Blog pages show at most"

Comment: Hi Robert Hue, I did change this parameter but it did not change anything. Even more weird : when I set the blog pages to show at most 2 articles, it still displays 5 custom post types!

Comment: where is the query that you are doing?

Comment: Hi Mark Kaplun, the query is not in this page. This is my query : 
`<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'fiche-produit',
 'nopaging' => true);
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $i++;
 $the_query->the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable cause of this is the incorrect use of `pre_get_posts`, so I would look in my functions.php for any instance of `pre_get_posts`. I would suspect that `pre_get_posts` is used to set `posts_per_page` to 5 across the complete site.

Irrelevenat, but you make use of the build in loop counter `$wp_query->current_post` as a counter in stead of creating your own counter

Comment: Thank you so much Pieter! The problem was actually not in the functions.php but in a file called custom_functions.php in my parent theme, so I did replace `pre_get_posts` with `posts_per_page` and it worked !
I'm a bit disapointed though, because this is gonna be a struggle for the next update of my theme. Lets hope the never change that line so I can edit it that way every time...